# How to call a stored procedure with JSON output in EF Core 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-5.0

I have a stored procedure with a JSON format output. You know that a JSON format output is in a string format.

Database context object returns only table type.

EX:

```
_context.tableA.FromSqlRaw()
```

But my scenario doesn't have any type except string.

How can I call this stored procedure with a string output and render the result to the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use output parameter

```
var output = new SqlParameter();
output.ParameterName = "@jsonOutput";
output.SqlDbType =  SqlDbType.NVarChar;
output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

var param1 = new SqlParameter();
output.ParameterName = "@ID";
output.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;


await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
"EXEC dbo.SpName @ID={0} @jsonOutput={1} OUT", param1,output);

var json =output.Value;
```

stored procedure

```
...
SET @jsonOutput = (SELECT ....
    FROM ...
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
...
```